# Krull dimension of polynomial ring in countably many variables

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, polynomial-rings

How can I prove that the Krull dimension of the polynomial ring $R=K[X_1,X_2,...]$ in countably many variables ($K$ a field) is infinity ? I have already proved that $R$ is an integral domain but *not* Noetherian, because $(X_1)\subsetneq(X_1,X_2)\subsetneq\cdots$ is a chain of ideals that does not stabilise at some point. I know that the Krull dimension is the supremum of the heights of all prime ideals of the ring and that the Krull dimension of the polynomial ring $K[X_1,...,X_n]$ in *finitely* many variables is equal to $n$. How can I efficiently apply this knowledge in order to compute the Krull dimension for *countably* many variables ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: It seems you have a chain of **prime** ideals. This should be enough to conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

For any $n\in\mathbf N$, there exists a  prime ideal of height $n$. Namely,
$$(X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n)\varsupsetneq(X_1, X_2,\dots, X_{n-1})\varsupsetneq\dots\varsupsetneq(X_1, X_2)\varsupsetneq (X_1)\varsupsetneq\{0\}$$
is a chain of prime ideals with length $n$.